# How can I add the values in one column based on dates and times in another?

Tags: excel, date, multiple-columns, addition

I have an Excel Spreadsheet that contains multiple columns. There are two that are of primary interest.

> [SAMPLE DATA]
>
> Date & Start Time (BST) | # students
>
> 19/05/2021 09:00 | 67
>
> 19/05/2021 09:00 | 26
>
> 19/05/2021 14:00 | 9
>
> 19/05/2021 15:00 | 153

These are "Date and Time" and "Number of People".

I need to be able to add the Number of People for a specific Date and Time and split them into Morning and Afternoon.

> [DESIRED RESULTS]
>
> 19/05/2021 Morning | 93
>
> 19/05/2021 Afternoon | 162

I don't know Excel very well, but I'm assuming that there are formulae that could accomplish this task. Could somebody let me know how this is done?

Comment: I'll edit the original post. thanks

Comment: `SUMIFS`; `Power Query` with Grouping; and other methods also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input, but I couldn't get the expected answers using them, but I found that a Pivot table did the trick.